# Rails + Devise: How to use cookie to log in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, devise

I'm upgrading a Rails 2 app to Rails 3, and in the past, it used AuthenticatedSystems where it would use cookie[:auth_token] to sign in:

```
def logged_in?
  current_user != :false
end

def current_user
  @current_user ||= (login_from_session || login_from_basic_auth || login_from_cookie || :false)
        if @current_user != :false && @current_user.logged_in_by_password == true
            session[:logged_in_by_password] = true
        end
        @current_user
end

def login_from_cookie
  user = cookies[:auth_token] && User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:auth_token])
  if user && user.remember_token?
    user.remember_me
    cookies[:auth_token] = { :value => user.remember_token, :expires => user.remember_token_expires_at, :http_only => true }
    self.current_user = user
  end
end
```

So all I would have to do is add this to my sessions controller on #create:

```
def create
  ...
  cookies[:auth_token] = { :value => self.current_user.remember_token , :expires => self.current_user.remember_token_expires_at, :http_only => true }
end
```

I'm using Devise now, and I think it uses sessions to log in. However, I want it to use a cookie for when the session doesn't exist. This is so that when the user closes his/her browser and reopens it, the rails app still has a way of logging them in automatically (I need this functionality for my shopping cart).

I tried adding the `cookies[:auth_token] = ...` line in my new `SesssionsController < Devise::SessionsController`, but I don't know how to make Devise do the same there where it tries different methods (looking at the sessions, cookies, etc). Is there anything similar in Devise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise uses the `session` hash to store its authentication information through the support of Warden.
Yet, keep in mind that [session information are typically stored in a cookie](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session), so if you're looking for persistence of a user's session, you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: I need to use a cookie in this case because I'm using `:active_record_store` for my sessions.

Comment: In that case, I'm afraid you'll have to basically overwrite much of Devise code, because (as to my knowledge) cookies are not supported. theoretically, it could be just a matter of forking the project, then replace `session[` with `cookies[` all over the place. and good luck.

Comment: Yeh... doesn't look like there's this type of functionality. I'll just have to write it myself then